# iOS - Connecting to socket with TLS-PSK

Tags: ios, sockets, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I'm building an iOS client that connects to a TCP socket with SSL/TLS and a pre-shared key, no certificate file. I'm trying to figure out if there's built-in support for TLS-PSK in iOS, but I can't seem to find any info anywhere. Am I missing something or will I have to use something like OpenSSL (which already made me cry two times) to get this to work?

I've been playing around with CFStream, NSStream and [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) without success.

For Android I'm using [SpongyCastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/).

Really appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share me how did you build a client with TLS and pre shared key in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OpenSSL you can definitely use TLS-PSK. You'll need to enable PSK cipher suites and also set the client callback using SSL_set_psk_client_callback from which you then provide the PSK.

P. S. On Android, TLS-PSK is also offered by the platform-default TLS stack since API Level 21 (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/PskKeyManager.html).

Comment: Would it be possible to use OpenSSL together with CFStream? Just for the TLS parts.

Comment: @nilsd did you get this working? And specifically with CocoaAsyncSocket?

Comment: @NiallMccormack I can't really remember but I believe I managed to solve it with OpenSSL alone.

Comment: @NiallMccormack How did you achieve PSK part in TLS.Share me the details

Comment: @nilsd just saw this. I can share a class with you if you like. Hobbled it together using OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a package to handle iOS to NodeJS on TLS taking into account latest Apple restrictions, check it out - https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets